# Calcular porcentagem de um rosto em uma imagem

Tags: ios, processamento-de-imagens, opencv

Como seria o cálculo de porcetangem de um rosto em uma imagem? Suponhamos que eu tenha uma foto 3x4 de um usuário, mas ele estivesse com boa parte do cabelo tampando o rosto. Existiria alguma forma de detectar que a imagem não possui uma porcentagem mínima com do rosto do usuário?

Comment: Com reconhecimento de formas você pode procurar por elementos, como bocas, olhos e cabelo. Daí você pode contar a quantidade de elementos presentes. Mas porcentagem de área exposta não pode ser feita com precisão, pois as pessoas têm rostos com formatos diferentes.

Comment: O Sistema do Detran-MG possui um mecanismo quando a foto para a CNH é tirada. Ele calcula 70% de rosto em uma imagem. Vou fazer um teste de reconhecimento facial e fazer alguns cálculos. Acho que pode resolver.

Comment: O @Renan e o karlphillip têm razão. Você até consegue fazer algo: uma ideia que me ocorre é usar o Haar Cascade pra detectar a região da face, e encontrando-a usar um classificador próprio para prever se cada pixel é ou não de pele; por fim, a razão entre os pixels classificados como "de pele" e o total de pixels na região da face resulta numa estimativa da porcentagem de face exibida. Porém, essa estimativa deve variar muito com o tamanho da região detectada (principalmente por causa de rotação), e com erros do classificador de pele para cabelo próximos do tom da pele, por exemplo.

Comment: O seu objetivo é validar que a pessoa esteja suficientemente visível na foto? A aplicação é séria (tipo a CNH que você menciona) e o ambiente de tomada da foto mais ou menos controlado? Porque se os possíveis erros de estimação não forem graves no domínio, ou o usuário puder ser instruído a posicionar corretamente o rosto, a ideia que eu sugeri pode ser útil.

Comment: Pode ser útil para referência futura (sua ou de outros): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118221/73

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os algoritmos de detecção facial funcionam a partir *features* (características) faciais. Assim, determinadas *features* devem estar presentes na foto para que o algoritmo consiga extrair os dados necessários e determinar se o objeto sendo avaliado é uma face ou não.

**É completamente possível ter uma porcentagem alta de exposição de uma face na foto e ainda assim a detecção falhar se os *features* certos forem escondidos/manipulados, como a pose, expressão facial, iluminação, etc.**

Portanto, pensar no sucesso da detecção facial como se ela dependesse de uma porcentagem mínima de exposição do rosto na foto não é uma abordagem realística.

Recomendo o artigo [Eigenfaces vs Fishfaces](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~belhumeur/journal/fisherface-pami97.pdf), da Universidade de Columbia (1997), que discute uma técnica mais robusta para solucionar esses problemas e faz uma comparação interessante com os 2 algoritmos mais populares de detecção/reconhecimento facial.